# how can I find a recursive relation for this code?

Tags: recursion, time-complexity

I think this code goes through a loop. Besides I think "do something different" won't get to be done anyway, so I don't know how to find the recursive relation and time complexity of it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
1F( n : integer )
2  { 
3    if n == 1 then 
4      “Do something”; 
5   else 
6   { 
7    for i = 1 to n do 
8    { 
9     F( i – 1 ); 
10     “Do something different”; 
11    } 
12   } 
13  }
```

Comment: This code is suspicious; you wrote an explicit base case for `n==1`, but for every `n >= 2` you make a recursive call to `F(0)`.

Comment: Why do you think `Do something different` will not be executed? It will be executed immediately after the recursive call to `F(i-1)` terminates.

Comment: @stef actually I mean "Do something different" will never happen. It'll go through a loop but that line won't run. I don't know if I'm right or not.

Comment: This line will run. Why do you think it wouldn't run?

Comment: @Stef if n=3, it's not 1 so "else" would happen and we'll turn back to line1 but this time n=2. again n isn't 1 so the same thing would happen.  I don't exactly understand when "Do something else"  would run.

Comment: Take this function: `fact(n: integer) { if (n <= 1) then return 1; else { x = fact(n-1); return n * x; } }`. There is a recursive call to `fact(n-1)`; this call is followed by `return n * x;`. Do you think `return n * x;` is not executed?

Comment: @Stef Yeah I got it. It'll be executed. And the recursive relation depends on it. right? but does it make a difference if I put line 10 first and then line 9. I mean if "do something else" came before F(i-1).

Answer (score 0):

Let's execute the algorithm in python to see what happens:

```py
def do_something(n, depth):
  print('  ' * depth + '[THEN] n={}'.format(n))

def do_something_different(n, i, depth):
  print('  ' * depth + '[ELSE] n={} i={}'.format(n, i))

def f(n, depth=0):
  if n == 1:
    do_something(n, depth)
  else:
    for i in range(1, n+1):
      f(i-1, depth+1)
      do_something_different(n, i, depth)

f(3)
```

Output:

```
[ELSE] n=3 i=1
  [THEN] n=1
[ELSE] n=3 i=2
  [ELSE] n=2 i=1
    [THEN] n=1
  [ELSE] n=2 i=2
[ELSE] n=3 i=3
```

As you can see, `do_something_different` is executed several times. Just because there is a recursive call to `F(i-1)` does not mean that `“Do something different”;` will not be executed. The recursive call is executed; once it is over, `“Do something different”;` is executed.

### Getting a recurrence relation on the complexity

If `n > 1`, we will enter the `for`-loop. The complexity in that case is the sum of the complexities of every iteration of the loop. Thus it is the sum of the complexities of every call `F(i-1)`, plus the sum of the complexities of `“Do something different”;`. If we assume that the complexity of `“Do something different”;` is the same at every iteration of the loop (*i.e.*, it does not depend on the value of `i`), then the complexity of `F(n)` for n>1 is:

```
Complexity(F(n)) =  sum(i=1..n) ( Complexity(F(i-1)) + Complexity(“Do something different” )
                 = ( sum(i=1..n) Complexity(F(i-1)) ) + n * Complexity(“Do something different”)
                 = ( sum(i=0..n-1) Complexity(F(i)) ) + n * Complexity(“Do something different”)
```

Comment: thank you so much. I had a very bad misunderstanding.